# In 他是一个不负责的人，（要／想） 当我们的经理, does it matter if I use 要 or 想?

Tags: grammar

> 他是一个不负责的人，（要／想） 当我们的经理。

Which is the right optative verb to use?

Comment: 要 means 'ask for'
想 means 'wanna'

Comment: 要 could also mean 'will be'.

Comment: their meaning is different，see e。g。＂实用现代汉语语法＂第二编 词类 第四章 动词 第六节 能源动词 三、能源动词分类（一）要１。表示有做某事的意思。例如：１他看我年纪大了，没月都把要买的东西送来。２毕业以后，我还要回到农村来。３你们要把愫方怎么样？４这个孩子，今天要去动物园不可。表示否定意思时北方人不用＂不要＂，而用＂不想＂、＂不打算＂。例如:５甲：他要去东北，你呢？乙：我不想去东北。６甲：今天晚上我要看电影，你看不看？乙：我不打算看。南方人可以说＂不要＂。例如：７。这种滥电影我不要看。８我不要吃这么甜的东西。２。表示事实上或情理上的需要，有＂应该、需要＂的意思，多用于未然的情况。例如：１这么好的青年，当然要表扬了。２你不要送了，把大娘交给我了。３这个方法也要介绍到老百姓那里去。４要建立和健全合理的规章制度。５干活的时候可要用脑子好好想一想。３。表示＂可能＂、＂会＂的意思，但语气比＂可能＂，＂会＂更肯定。例如：１。你这样自以为是是要栽跟头的。２脱离群众，十个有十个要失败。表达否定的意思用＂不会＂、＂不可能＂。例如：３甲：你这样固执是要出问题的！乙：你放心，不会（不可能）出问题。４。用来表示一种看法、估计，用于比较句。例如：１天气预报说今天气温上升，我怎么觉得今天比昨天要冷一点呢？２报告说明年的经济形势要比今年好。３我觉得姐姐要比妹妹聪明。

Comment: According to the context, both are possible.

Comment: comment＃１continued，
＂要＂还有很多意思和用法，如表示＂索取＂、＂要求＂（动词），＂将要＂（副词），表示＂如果＂(连词）的意思。等等。（二）想 能源词＂想＂表示＂愿望＂、＂打算＂。例如：１他想尽可能了解他们，然后再做他们的思想工作。２甫志高几次想问，却不好启齿。３除了我，谁也不想打败他。４小刘，我想跟你聊聊。５今天的活动我不想参加了。与＂要＂相比，＂想＂表示的是一种愿望、想法，而＂要＂表示的是一种意志，在语义上要强得多。因此＂要＂前可以加上＂一定＂、＂非。。。不可＂这种表示强烈愿望、意志的词语，＂想＂则不然，可以加上表示程度浅的＂有（一）点儿＂。例如：６这个孩子非要抽烟不可，你说怎么办？７如果你一定要去，我也拦不住你。３我有点儿想去游泳，你去吗？但是＂很＂只能用在＂要＂前。例如：９听说那个地方很有意思，我很想去看看。＂想＂还用作动词，意思是＂思念＂、＂思索＂。

Comment: 要 here mostly mean 'will be'

Comment: 但还想 will be best. He's an irresponsible guy BUT但 STILL还  WANTS TO想 be our manager. The original two choices make no sense to a native Chinese.

Comment: This is a very odd sentence to me as a native Chinese speaker, it's better to put 但 or 还 in the middle.

Comment: Agreed with CYC; it does not look like a complete sentence at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the word "想" in this case. I think the sentence you're trying to write is:

He is an irresponsible person, he thinks he is our boss / manager.

Using the word "要" in this context speaking about an "irresponsible person" doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence "他是一个不负责的人，（要／想） 当我们的经理", there is difference between "要" and "想". "要" may mean "will" (将要), while "想" means "want".

Answer (score 0):

Actually "要/想" are both OK, it depends on what you mean in this sentence.

I guess you mean he is not responsible, "but" he wants to be the manager, in which case I suggest you use "想"； if you mean he will be, use "要".

In fact, adding a “但” in front of “要/想” can better express the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what meaning you want to express. 
If the man will supposedly be your manager, use 要. However, I feel this expression is slightly unnatural. 
If the man is eager to be your manager (although he lacks sense of responsibility), use 想. 
And...if thinking in a typical Chinese way, this sentence may come out of a test paper...
I recommend 想, for it seems to be more "optative".